# How to find the square side length in this problem?

Tags: statistics

[image]

Am I assuming the sides are 12 and 18 then? But it is a square chess board, so that can't be right. Can someone please explain this please?

Comment: Are you familiar with a uniform distribution over the reals? The size of the board is $ s \times s$, where $ s \sim U[12,18]$.

Comment: The boards are anywhere from $12\times12$ to $18\times18$.

Comment: The side length is a random number between 12 and 18. "Since each chess board is uniquely handcrafted"..."X is uniformly distributed between 12 and 18 inches."

Comment: from what I read on the internet, would the expected area be 15 then? "The notation for the uniform distribution is X ~ U(a, b) where a = the lowest value of x and b = the highest value of x."